# AG-GRID - Unable to fetch data from REST

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

i,ve been pulling hair with what I tought was going to be a simple code. I admit that i am quite new to typescript and learning as I go but more familiar with javascript.

I am basically creating a SPA (Single Page Application) using AG-GRID as my maine component. I have a service which pulls data from a REST connection (currently using JSON server to mimick that) and will share that data across multiple components. AG-GRID seems to be the only component refusing to work correctly at the moment. I am getting the error below.

Ive been scavaging the internet for solution for a few weeks now but cant find an exmaple that matches my situation. Would anyone here know what to do with the error below?

Console Error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(data: Incident_Model) => Incident_Model' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Incident_Model[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Incident_Model[]' is not assignable to type 'Incident_Model'.
      Property 'id' is missing in type 'Incident_Model[]'.
```

Angular interface:

```
export class Incident_Model {
    id: number;
    Incident: string;
    status: string;
}
```

Angular service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Incident_Model } from './incident_model';

const BackEnd_URL = environment.BackEnd_URL;

@Injectable()
export class BackEndService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }

  getAllIncidents(): Observable<Incident_Model[]> {

    return this.http.get<Incident_Model[]>(BackEnd_URL + '/Incidents');

  }

}
```

Angular Component:

```
ngOnInit() {this.backendservice.getAllIncidents().subscribe( data => this.gridOptions.api.setRowData = data )}
```

**Updated with code in comment below - 11h37 - 2018-02-07:**
Here is the full component code just in case someone can spot something im missing:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GridOptions } from "ag-grid";
import { BackEndService } from '../../Shared/back-end.service';
import { Incident_Model } from '../../Shared/incident_model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-archive',
  templateUrl: './archive.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./archive.component.css']
})
export class ArchiveComponent implements OnInit {

  private gridOptions: GridOptions;

  constructor(private backendservice: BackEndService) { 

    var gridSize = 8;
    var rowHeight = gridSize * 6;
    var headerHeight = gridSize * 7;

    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
      enableFilter: true,
      enableColResize: true,
      enableSorting: true,
      pagination: true,
      paginationPageSize:25,
      animateRows: true,
      headerHeight: headerHeight,
      rowHeight:rowHeight         
    };

    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Headname here",
        children:[
        {
              headerName: "id",
              field: "id",
              width: 165,
              filterParams: { applyButton: true, clearButton:true }
          },
          {
              headerName: "Incident",
              field: "Incident",
              width: 450,
              filterParams: { applyButton: true, clearButton:true }
          },
          {
            headerName: "status",
            field: "status",
            width: 110,
            filterParams: { applyButton: true, clearButton:true }
          }
    ];

  }

  ngOnInit() {this.backendservice.getAllIncidents().subscribe(data => this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(data)) }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, data for should be passed as a parameter instead of an assignement:

```
this.backendservice.getAllIncidents().subscribe(data => this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(data));
```

Comment: Ok thanks, gave that a try but still seeing the same errors:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'Incident_Model' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Incident_Model'.

Comment: Well after reloading my angular CLI (ng serve) the error magically went away. I think this was a silly mistake on my part, I tought it was something much more complex than that lol. Thanks again Alexander!